# best way to import 500MB csv file into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, import

I have a 500MB csv file that needs to be imported into my mysql database.

I've written a PHP script where I can upload the csv file to and it analyses the fields and does the actual importing. but it can only handle small files of max. 5MB. So that's a 100 files and actually pretty slow(uploading)

Is there another way? I have to repeat this process every month because the data in the file changes every month it's about 12 000 000 lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the file contains consistently-formed CSV (there is no standard, so you'll likely want to test extensively before importing over any production tables) you can skip PHP altogether and use MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement after uploading the data to the server.

(If you don't have immediate access to the mysql console on the server, this could also be accomplished with a very simple PHP script or with phpMyAdmin)

Comment: I tried running this in the sql tab of phpmyadmin LOAD DATA INFILE "/public_html/csv/bigfile.csv" INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' but got an error saying access denied, what do you mean when you say I can do it with phpmyadmin? I tried the import option there but it only allows 50MB and timeouts when using files bigger than 5mb

Comment: I was talking about using phpMyAdmin in place of the MySQL console (as you were doing). The "access denied" error could be related to file or database permissions - could you post the full error message?

Comment: ok I tried the doing it trough php instead of phpmyadmin and it worked as I could use a relative path to the file... and its really really fast... thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be:

- using a tool like [SQLyog] which has a free "community" version you can download [here](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list).
   You might find useful SQLyog FAQ about [importing CSV data](http://www.webyog.com/faq/28_73_en.html)
- import it [via SSH][4] (you can transfer database dump using an FTP and then just execute 
  `mysql -p -u username database_name < file.sql`